# DLL Property no settable

Tags: c#, dll

Why Could I not set my Property? 
The DLL is imported and all methods are reachable but the URL property wont show up and also seems to not exists
http://prntscr.com/6y2az8

Dll Code:

```
namespace Steap
{
    public class SteapAPI
    {
        public static String URL
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public static XmlReader r = XmlReader.Create("");

        public int getSteamID64()
        {
            int ID = 0;
            r.ReadToFollowing("steamID64");
            ID = r.ReadContentAsInt();
            return ID;
        }

        public string getSteamID()
        {
            string ID = String.Empty;
            r.ReadToFollowing("steamID");
            ID = r.ReadContentAsString();
            return ID;
        }

        public string getName()
        {
            return getSteamID();
        }

    }
}
```

I also used string intead of String and I need the static for the later statement

Comment: Now is your chance to learn how to participate in the process by accepting the answer which was most helpful.  Just click the checkmark next to it.

Comment: As a side note, remember that C# isn't Java. Those method names should start with a capital letter!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the image that you added you are trying to access it like this:

```
SteapAPI sapi = new SteapAPI);
sapi.URL = // ... do something
```

Your property is static, so you should call it from class and not from instance:

```
SteapAPI.URL = // ... do something
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't noticed that!

Answer (score 0):

Static properties are on the class not the instance. Use

SteapAPI.URL

Keep in mind this means the value is shared by all instances of the class.

Answer (score 0):

If it is static then you access it like

```
SteapAPI.URL
```